# can i do angular2 project in angular4 environment?

Tags: angular, package, version, package.json

I cloned a project from github repo git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart Demo  and package.json content is below,

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "0.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I have to work in Angular2.Is that Angular2 or Angular4 and can I use this for Angular2, I am new to angular please help. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: why you want to use angular version 2 ? version 2 is canda old, you should use at least version 4 or better version 5

Answer (score 0):

Angular 4 is just a new version of angular 2.And yes you can happily do that,but it's better if you choose a new version as it contains few new features in it.